# On click only works once

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mobile-website

for my responsive (mobile) hamburger-menu, i wanted to show the menu, when a class is pressed.
But it only works once ('click' is only locked once in the console, so it doesn't register the clicks after it was pressed one time). NOTE: I use PHP for the side and for the menu html.

What is my mistake? Thank you for your advice!

```js
var btn = document.querySelector(".toggle-btn");
var navbar = document.querySelector(".menue");
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('click');
  navbar.classList.toggle("active");
})
```

````html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="nav-bar">
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="../../index.php"><img src="../png/lg_nord_logo_navbar.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="toggle-btn">
      <span class="bar">Bar 1</span>
      <span class="bar">Bar 2</span>
      <span class="bar">Bar 3</span>
    </a>
    <div class="menue">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Disziplinen</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="../disziplinen/30_m_startblock.php">30 meter startblock</a></li>
            <li><a href="../disziplinen/30_m_fliegend.php">30 meter fliegend</a></li>
            <li><a href="../disziplinen/60m.php">60 meter</a></li>
            <li><a href="../disziplinen/10er_hopserlauf.php">10er Hopserlauf</a></li>
            <li><a href="../disziplinen/Klappmesser.php">Klappmesser</a></li>
            <li><a href="../disziplinen/Klimmzuege.php">Klimmzüge</a></li>
            <li><a href="../disziplinen/liegestuetze.php">Liegestütze</a></li>
            <li><a href="../disziplinen/standweitsprung.php">Standweitsprung</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Daten hinzufügen</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="../addData/30_m_startblock.php">30 meter startblock</a></li>
            <li><a href="../addData/30_m_fliegend.php">30 meter fliegend</a></li>
            <li><a href="../addData/60m.php">60 meter</a></li>
            <li><a href="../addData/10er_hopserlauf.php">10er Hopserlauf</a></li>
            <li><a href="../addData/Klappmesser.php">Klappmesser</a></li>
            <li><a href="../addData/Klimmzuege.php">Klimmzüge</a></li>
            <li><a href="../addData/liegestuetze.php">Liegestütze</a></li>
            <li><a href="../addData/standweitsprung.php">Standweitsprung</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">support_agent</i>Athleten (beta)</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="../athlet_search/index.php?name=tom">Tom-Luca</a></li>
            <li><a href="../athlet_search/index.php?name=marc">Marc          </a></li>
            <li><a href="../athlet_search/index.php?name=leo">Leo          </a></li>
            <li><a href="../athlet_search/index.php?name=lukas">Lukas</a></li>
            <li><a href="../athlet_search/index.php?name=vincent">Vincent</a></li>
            <li><a href="../athlet_search/index.php?name=damien">Damien</a></li>
            <li><a href="../athlet_search/index.php?name=karsten">Karsten</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="../../settings/"><i class="material-icons">admin_panel_settings</i> Einstellungen</a></li>
        <li><a class="state" href="login.php">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="../logout.php"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>  Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```
````

My PHP code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
  header("Location: ../index.php");
  exit;
}
require("../rank_manager.php");
if(getRank($_SESSION["username"]) == USER){
  header("Location: ../errors/error.php?code=101&name=not_enought_permissions&type=website");
    exit;
}
if(isBanned($_SESSION["username"])){
  header("Location: logout.php");
  exit;
}


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#34495e">
    <title>Daten hinzufügen</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.theme.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c54c107c6a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript "src="../../theme/themeManager.js" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript "src="navbar_menu.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body class="light">
    <div class="themeChange">
      <button id="changeTheme"><i class="material-icons">dark_mode</i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="preloader">
        <img src="../png/preloader-final.gif" alt="">
    </div>

    
    <?php
        include("../navbar/navbar.html");
    ?>

    <div class="data">
      <form action="standweitsprung.php" method="post">

          <h1>Daten eintragen</h1>
          <br><br>
        
          <input type="text" name="period"  placeholder="Zeitraum">
          
          <input name="tom" id="tom_input"  type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Tom">

          <input name="marc" id="marc_input"  type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Marc">

          <input  name="leo" id="leo_input"  type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Leo">

          <input name="lukas" id="lukas_input"  type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Lukas">

          <input name="vincent" id="vincent_input"  type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Vincent">

          <input name="damien" id="damien_input"  type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Damien">

          <input name="karsten" id="karsten_input"  type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Karsten">

          <button type="submit" name="submit">Daten absenden</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
        $period = $_POST["period"];
        $tom = $_POST["tom"];
        $marc = $_POST["marc"];
        $leo = $_POST["leo"];
        $lukas = $_POST["lukas"];
        $vincent = $_POST["vincent"];
        $damien = $_POST["damien"];
        $karsten = $_POST["karsten"];

        if($tom == "") {
          $tom = null;
        }
        if($lukas == "") {
          $lukas = null;
        }
        if($leo == "") {
          $leo = null;
        }
        if($marc == "") {
          $marc = null;
        }
        if($vincent == "") {
          $vincent = null;
        }
        if($damien == "") {
          $damien = null;
        }
        if($karsten == "") {
          $karsten = null;
        }

        $content = array(
          "period" => $period,
          "tom" => $tom,
          "marc" => $marc,
          "leo" => $leo,
          "lukas" => $lukas,
          "vincent" => $vincent,
          "damien" => $damien,
          "karsten" => $karsten,
        );

        if(filesize("../data/standweitsprung.json") == 0) {
          $first_record = array($content);
          $data_to_save = $first_record;
        } else {
          $old_records = json_decode(file_get_contents("../data/standweitsprung.json"));
          array_push($old_records, $content);

          $data_to_save = $old_records;
        }
        if(!(file_put_contents("../data/standweitsprung.json", json_encode($data_to_save, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT), LOCK_EX))) {
          $error = "Error storing content";
        } else {
          $success = "Daten gespeichert";
        }
    }
     ?>

    <div class="turn-device">
        <img src="../png/rotate-device-light.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <script src="../javascript/preloader.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added some text in the spans and the code works as expected

Comment: I don't see how the PHP code is relevant at all here. When you have issues with client side code (like JS), you should rather look at the generated code that's sent to the browser (right click on the page and "view source").

Comment: `addEventListener()` seems to work fine for me, the `toggle()` work properly. 'click' also log every time I clicked, not just once.

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed it. The problem was that the mobile nav-bar had rendered a transparent object on top of the button, so I never clicked the button actually. The solution was to give the button a higher z-index.